# How to check the existence of a Group in Windows

Tags: powershell

I have successfully been able to determine if a specified user exists under DOMAIN/User but I am not sure of the best way to determine if a group exists under a specific domain.

Has anyone created a solution for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ADSI]::Exists("WinNT://$srvName/$grpName,group")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the adsisearcher type shortcut:

```
 ([adsisearcher]'(&(objectClass=group)(samaccountname=group1))').FindOne()
```